# Appropriate coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Show that $$C^{2}_{2n} \sum^n_{k=0} \left(C^k_n\right)^2$$

Attempt: I tried to match the appropriate coefficients of $ x ^ m $ on both sides of $$ (x + 1) ^ n \cdot (x + 1) ^ n = (x + 1) ^ {2n}$$ $$  (x+1)^m \cdot (1+x)^n =(1+x)^{m+n} $$

a) $$C^1_m + c^1_n = C^1_{m+n}$$

b) $$C^2_m+C^1_mC^1_n+C^2_n=C^2_{m+n}$$

c) $$C^k_{m+n}= \sum^k_{i=0}C^{k-i}_m \cdot C^i_n$$ (Vandermonde convolution)

Comment: Should there be an "$=$" somewhere?

Comment: The notation $C_n^k$ to denote the number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$ element set is very uncommon and directly conflicts with the slightly more common notation $C^n_k$ to mean the same thing.  It is highly recommended to avoid both of these and use instead the notation $\binom{n}{k}$.  Of course, use whatever notation your teacher uses while in their class, but you ought to be aware of the different notations so that you can read what other people write and when you have the freedom to choose your notation you should use one that avoids confusion for readers as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:*

Write the first $(1+x)^n$ as $$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} x^r $$ and the second one as $$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} x^{n-r} $$ Now multiply these and find the coefficient of $x^n$.